# Build error after updated Angular to 6.1 from 5.2 in view.d.ts

Tags: angular

On updating Angular from 5.2 to **6.1**.

Facing this mentioned build errors in file view.d.ts, bypass.d.ts, container.d.ts.

( we are using Systemjs.Config.js, Gulpfile.js in the application )

*Build: A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. node_modules@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\view.d.ts*

Package.json is as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP20B.jpg)

If require more info, please suggest.

Comment: did you follow the steps officially provided by angular for the update?

Comment: Yes, i followed. 

Only clue i got till yet, it may or may not be related to typescript file.